# Mobile device detection

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design

I need precise function to detect mobile platform (mobile and tablets).

There are 2 awesome answers about that:

1. [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)
2. [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

But first solution, which is based on http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ does not work in all cases. For example it doesn't recognize `Motorola Moto Z` as mobile platform:

```
window.mobileAndTabletcheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

Both topics are 7-9 years aged and it might be the reason why they do not support latest versions.

Is there any proven solution for modern mobile devices?

Comment: Note that some of the answers on the second question advise the use of things other than user agent parsing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364620/215552 for instance, uses CSS or the `matchMedia` API...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey today mobile devices, especially tablets may have high resolution, therefore it isn't a good solution to look at the screen resolution

Comment: It's also trivially easy to spoof user agent strings. Maybe you should concentrate on detecting the features of mobile devices that you want to target. For instance, other answers on that question method detecting touch events. Maybe you want to detect if the device has an accelerometer. Concentrate on what it is about the device that you want to program to and check for that, rather than what make and model of device the user is using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally the best solution for now is using `"maxTouchPoints"` detection. According to **MDN recommendations**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile_Device_Detection  `Navigator.maxTouchPoints` should be used to detect if the user's device has a touchscreen. Then, default back to checking the user agent screen. To take into account desktops and laptops with touch screen, we can check min device with which remains the same even if to resize window to smaller size.

Notice that `Agent` check is used as fallback solution. But in this example it is rather shallow and should be enhanced. Before that I've used nice solution from this old post: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser). It user regex from **detectmobilebrowsers.com**.
But it doesn't cover all cases especially new ones (in my case `Motorolla`). Therefore Agent check I've used from the **`mobile-detect.js`**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect. And now it looks great and version safe.

```
    let hasTouchScreen = false;
    if ("maxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
        hasTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
    } else if ("msMaxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
        hasTouchScreen = navigator['msMaxTouchPoints'] > 0;
    } else {
        let mQ = window.matchMedia && matchMedia("(pointer:coarse)");
        if (mQ && mQ.media === "(pointer:coarse)") {
            hasTouchScreen = !!mQ.matches;
        } else if ('orientation' in window) {
            hasTouchScreen = true; // deprecated, but good fallback
        }
    }

    const md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
    const isMobileDetected = Object.isNotNull(md.mobile()) || Object.isNotNull(md.phone()) || Object.isNotNull(md.tablet());

    return hasTouchScreen && md.isPhoneSized(600) || isMobileDetected;
```

`mobile-detect` can be substituted with some regexps. But it is not so efficient. Moreover, you should update it when new devices appear:

```
mobileAndTabletcheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [is.js](https://is.js.org/)? One of its features is mobile device detection. Example:

```
function mobileAndTabletCheck() {
  return is.mobile() || is.tablet();
}
```

It's a small library (13KB not gzipped) and it could fit your purpose exactly. It's also open source. Looking at the code, it seems to detect iOS, Android, Windows Phone, and Blackberry.